# Which enthought canopy distribution should I install?

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, enthought

I am running 32 bit Python on a 64 bit system.  Which enthought canopy distribution should I install? The 32 bit or the 64 bit?

In other words, do I match the operating system I am using or do I match the Python I am using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You install a 64bit Operating System.

And you should install a 32bit Python version **only if**:

- The libraries you intend to use does not support a 64bit Python version.
- You intend to build your .py into a .exe
- You're testing something specific related to the 32bit arch.

Otherwise, install a 64bit Python and a newer python version (Python 3.X) if possible.

Comment: Hi the reason I am using the 32 bit python is for points 1 & 2 The libraries I intend to use do not support a 64bit Python version.
I also intend to build your .py projects into .exe's

Comment: Then install Python 32bit, the Operating system has very little to do with your Python version as it will emulate a 32bit runtime environment for you. And since you're bound to old libraries and you intend to build into a .exe a 32bit python is the better fit since you don't know which platform the software will run on. And again, the OS cares very little if you run a 32bit or 64bit Python, both will work equally fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will probably need to close this question I know non code specific questions get Stack Overflow all jittery, many thanks :)

Comment: Yw. (and not all of us hate on borderline SO-illegal questions) :) Gl!

Comment: Just to clarify one other part of your original question: "do I match the Python I am using". Canopy includes a full Python distribution. It operates (and must operate) independently of whatever other Python distributions you have installed (just as they operate independently of Canopy). If you want to share the same package between two Python distributions, you should install the package independently into both distributions. So either this question is meaningless or the answer is "no".